# Updating entity in Room database

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I have a problem in regards to updating a single entity in Room database. I had set up a single entity `User` which holds all the data relevant for the user, such as id, username, etc..

I am also using the ViewModel pattern, as well built Room with RxJava. Database is created in `MainActivity`, which also has the `userViewModel`:

```
factory = Injection.provideViewModelFactory(this);
userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(UserViewModel.class);
```

Then, I have a arbitrary set of operations to check whether or not the user data gets updated. I create the `User` object, set attributes, insert the `User` object to database, fetch the set attributes to make see if they get returned, re-set them and fetch them again to observe the changes (DISCLAIMER: this code is ugly and only serves helping/debugging purposes):

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setId("id");
    user.setUsername("username");
    Observable.just(userViewModel.insertUser(user))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Updating ...", "Updated User"));
    CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    Observable.just(userViewModel.getUserId()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "ID", s))
    );
    disposable.add(userViewModel.getUserName()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Username", s))
    );
    disposable.add(userViewModel.updateUserName("new username")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Completable", " called");
            })
    );
    disposable.add(userViewModel.updateId("20")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
    );
    Observable.just(userViewModel.getUserId()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "NEW ID", s))
    );
    Observable.just(userViewModel.getUserName()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "NEW Username", s))
    );
```

The update methods are as follows:

```
public Completable updateUserName(final String userName){
    Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Updating...", userName);
    return new CompletableFromAction(() -> {
        mUser = mUser == null
                ? new User(userName)
                : new User(mUser.getId(),userName);
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "New user", mUser.getUsername());
        mDataSource.updateUser(mUser);
    });
}

public Completable updateId(final String id){
    Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Updating....", id);
    return new CompletableFromAction( () -> {
        mUser = mUser == null
                ? new User()
                : new User(mUser.getId());
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "New id", mUser.getId());
        mUser.setId(id);
        mDataSource.updateUser(mUser);
    });
}
```

The `UserDao` method I'm using is:

```
@Update
fun updateUser(vararg user: User)
```

The constructor for `User` object:

```
constructor(){

}

@Ignore
constructor(userName: String) {
    this.username = username
}

constructor(id: String, userName: String) {
    this.id = id
    this.username = userName
}
```

When debugging and looking at the log statements, this is what I get:

```
11-23 21:44:25.131 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/Updating...: new username
11-23 21:44:25.134 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/Updating....: 20
11-23 21:44:25.835 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/Updating ...: Updated User
11-23 21:44:25.836 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/Completable:  called
11-23 21:44:25.836 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/Username: username
11-23 21:44:25.836 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/ID: id
11-23 21:44:25.836 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/NEW ID: id
11-23 21:44:25.836 15091-15091/com.myapp.app A/NEW Username: username
```

What am I doing wrong? Logs included in the `update(...)` methods are not shown, meaning there might be a problem with `CompletableFromAction`? Or I'm doing something completely wrong?